# How to transfer MKV file from Windows PC to iPad Mini

Tags: video, windows, apple-store

How do I transfer MKV file from Windows PC to iPad Mini? I have installed iTunes on Windows PC but I can't any option to transfer file.

Comment: If you want to watch it with Videos app you must convert it to compatible format and add to your iTunes library. If you want to move as is, you must use a thirty party solution.

Comment: I am using a third party solution Syncios but even there I can't see any option to transfer MKV files. MOV files tranfer option is there though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not bother with conversion. Install the free video players like VLC or PlayerXtreme and upload the videos via wifi directly to the apps.

EDIT: Alternatively, and also must faster for large files, both apps allow transfers via iTunes. If you don't use iTunes read on...

For example, once installed you enable Wifi Transfers...

[image: VLC app options]  [image: PlayerXtreme options]

Then from your browser you go to the address shown and upload the files...

[image: VLC upload]

Comment: VLC is currently not available in the app store for some reason. I hope it will be back soon.

Comment: Yes VLC has been removed. I have now converted MKV file to MOV and transferred it into Music. The "Syncios" software is showing that it is copied to "iTunes_Control/Music/F12/BHQP.mp4" path but I am unable to find it in iPad Mini.

Comment: @FrankMartin Does http://syncios.com/support/syncios-data-transfer-faq.html#part6 help?

Comment: Yeah I got it under Videos. But all this exercise was crap because in the converted video, audio is not syncd with video. So now I have to do conversion again using some other software and then transfer it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it as a multi-step approach

1. Convert your MKV video into an MP4/M4V which the iPad can play. On OS X there is software like [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) for this, I'm sure there are similar applications available on Windows.
2. Import the converted video into iTunes
3. Use iTunes to sync the video to your iPad

If you have troubles with one of these steps, there are various questions with answers for each of them on this site already. In case you can't find them, don't hesitate to ask a new question.